# How to download a file from server using smartgwt?

Tags: file, download, smartgwt

On a client operation, a file is created on the server and I want to allow the client to download that file.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always bring back the data to the client side with you rpc service sending an object.
You still can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053462/open-save-file-in-smartgwt)